# Is there a way to get Python all() function to work with multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, equality

I'm trying to implement a generic and flexible `__eq__` method for a base class that will work with as many object types as possible including iterables and numpy arrays.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Environment:

    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Compare two environments based on their states.
        """
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            try:
                return all(self.state == other.state)
            except TypeError:
                return self.state == other.state
        return False
```

This works fine for most object types including one-dimensional arrays:

```
s = 'abcdef'
e1 = Environment(s)
e2 = Environment(s)

e1 == e2  # True

s = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
e1 = Environment(s)
e2 = Environment(s)

e1 == e2  # True

s = np.array(range(6))
e1 = Environment(s)
e2 = Environment(s)

e1 == e2  # True
```

The problem is, it returns a ValueError when `self.state` is a numpy array that is multi-dimensional.

```
s = np.array(range(6)).reshape((2, 3))
e1 = Environment(s)
e2 = Environment(s)

e1 == e2
```

Produces:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Obviously, I could check for `isinstance(other, np.ndarray)` and then do `(return self.state == other.state).all()` but just thought there might be a more general way of handling all iterables, collections and arrays of any type with one statement.

I'm also a bit confused why `all()` doesn't iterate over all the elements of the array like `array.all()`.  Is there a way to trigger `np.nditer` and do that maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Signature: all(iterable, /)
Docstring:
Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
```

For a 1d array:

```
In [200]: x=np.ones(3)                                                               
In [201]: x                                                                          
Out[201]: array([1., 1., 1.])
In [202]: y = x==x                                                                   
In [203]: y          # 1d array of booleans                                                                      
Out[203]: array([ True,  True,  True])
In [204]: bool(y[0])                                                                 
Out[204]: True
In [205]: all(y)                                                                     
Out[205]: True
```

For a 2d array:

```
In [206]: x=np.ones((2,3))                                                           
In [207]: x                                                                          
Out[207]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
In [208]: y = x==x                                                                   
In [209]: y                                                                          
Out[209]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
In [210]: y[0]                                                                       
Out[210]: array([ True,  True,  True])
In [211]: bool(y[0])                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-d0ce0868392c> in <module>
----> 1 bool(y[0])

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

But for a different 2d array:

```
In [212]: x=np.ones((3,1))                                                           
In [213]: y = x==x                                                                   
In [214]: y                                                                          
Out[214]: 
array([[ True],
       [ True],
       [ True]])
In [215]: y[0]                                                                       
Out[215]: array([ True])
In [216]: bool(y[0])                                                                 
Out[216]: True
In [217]: all(y)                                                                     
Out[217]: True
```

Iteration on a numpy array occurs along the first dimension.  `[i for i in x]`

This ambiguity ValueError is raised any time a multivalued boolean array is used in a context that expects a scalar boolean.  `if` and `or/and` expressions are common ones.

```
In [223]: x=np.ones((2,3))                                                           
In [224]: y = x==x                                                                   
In [225]: np.all(y)                                                                  
Out[225]: True
```

`np.all` is different Python `all` in that it 'knows' about dimensions.  In this case it does a `ravel` to treat the array as 1d:

> The default (`axis` = `None`) is to perform a logical AND over all the dimensions of the input array.

Comment: Thanks.  So there is no one-line solution I guess.

Comment: The fact that numpy comparisons work element by element, means comparisons are fundamentally different from lists or tuples.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the concise solution I was hoping for and probably inefficient but I think it works with any n-dimensional iterable:

```
def nd_true(nd_object):
    try:
        iterator = iter(nd_object)
    except TypeError:
        return nd_object
    else:
        return all([nd_true(x) for x in iterator])

class Environment:

    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Compare two environments based on their states.
        """
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return nd_true(self.state == other.state)
        return False

# Tests    
s = 'abcdef'
e1 = Environment(s)
e2 = Environment(s)

e1 == e2  # True

s = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
e1 = Environment(s)
e2 = Environment(s)

e1 == e2  # True

s = np.array(range(6))
e1 = Environment(s)
e2 = Environment(s)

e1 == e2  # True

s = np.array(range(6)).reshape((2, 3))
e1 = Environment(s)
e2 = Environment(s)

e1 == e2  # True

s = np.array(range(27)).reshape((3, 3, 3))
e1 = Environment(s)
e2 = Environment(s)

e1 == e2  # True
```